# Struggling to find implicitly-defined function and its second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The question I am working on is as follows:

> Let $y$ be implicitly defined by $$\sin(x-y) - e^{xy} + 1=0$$ and $y(0) = 0$. Find $y''(0)$.

Any help with finding the implicit function and possibly its second derivative is greatly appreciated because I cannot seem to work it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you derivate it once you get:

$$\cos(x-y)(1-y') - e^{xy}(xy'+y) =0$$

and for $x=0$ we get $1-y'(0) = y(0)=0$ so $y'(0)=1$ and if we derivate it second time we get:

$$-\sin(x-y)(1-y')^2 -\cos(x-y)y''-e^{xy}(xy'+y)^2 -e^{xy}(xy''+2y')=0  $$

so for $x=0$ we get:

$$ -y''(0)-y(0)^2-2y'(0)=0\implies y''(0)=-2$$

Comment: I get it. Because we know there is an implicit function in the equation we can just derive it twice until we substitute. Thanks.

Comment: In $-\sin(x-y)(1-y')^2 \color{blue}{+}\cos(x-y)y''-e^{xy}(xy'+y)^2 -e^{xy}\color{red}{(xy'+y)}(xy''+2y')=0$, what is the red factor doing there? I also think the blue $+$ should be a $-$; this will change the outcome.